# How to know if user has pending apprequests without clicking requests?

Tags: facebook, notifications, apprequests

If user clicks my app's notifications, he is redirected to the corresponding canvas page, where $_REQUEST["request_ids"] is processed and then user is redirected again to "accept" the "gift", bla bla bla.

But: if user enters my app, without clicking notifications (1), I should find out a way to show the user a message "forcing" him to click the notifications (2) before!

Is there any way to get if user has pending "un-processed" notifications?

Please look @ image. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that when using Facebook PHP SDK, you can do

```
$pendingReqs = $facebook->api("/me/apprequests");
```

By checking the returned info you can know how much pending requests user has and loop through them

Hope this is useful for someone

info: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests